# Unable to connect to the (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: sql-server, localdb

> Cannot connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.)( Microsoft SQL server)

Yesterday I was able to connect to the (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB and was able to see all the databases in it in SQL server management studio. But today when I am trying to connect, am getting the above mentioned error.

How I was able to connect yesterday but why not now? Please help me.

Comment: Try running `sqlqlocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB` from a command prompt.

Comment: I have tried. It is giving me the error that the  start of LocaDB instance"MSSQLLocalDB" failed because of the following error: Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL server process failed to start.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for more detail error messages: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\mssqllocaldb\error.log`

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: I posted the path. Run `notepad "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\mssqllocaldb\error.log"` from a command prompt. Add the output to your question.

Comment: It is not recognising as a command.

Comment: The path I provided is for SQL 2019 localdb. The exact path may differ for older versions but there should be an error log file in the mssqllocaldb directory.

Comment: Am using SQL server 2019 only. But it's not working.

Comment: Do you see the directory on your machine? `dir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\mssqllocaldb"`

Comment: No. Am not finding it.

Comment: Does this command return anything? `Wmic /node:%COMPUTERNAME% product get name | findstr "LocalDB"`. Also check for related messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Getting "Invalid Global Switch"

Comment: It seems your computer name contains special characters. Try hard-coding the name and enclose it in single quotes: `Wmic /node:'your-computer-name' product get name | findstr "LocalDB"`

Comment: My computer name is like DESKTOP-9MGOUF. Now can u pls tell me the exact command what I have to give. And what this command will give? Also pls tell me about the event viewer. I don't know about that. I just opened it. What I need to check there?

Comment: In the event viewer, I have opened the Application section of windows logs. I have selected the error. Below in the General tab, something is displayed that " The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocaDB instance registry key: {1BC91CE3-6325-44C6-87B8-5B92E315257D}

Comment: The exact command is `Wmic /node:'DESKTOP-9MGOUF' product get name | findstr "LocalDB"`. It should return "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 LocalDB".  The missing registry value suggests your localdb instance is corrupt. You can recreate it with `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB` and `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB -s`. This will recreate the registry entries.

Comment: That command is not returning anything for me now. If I delete and recreate the MSSQLLocalDB, don't I loose my databases which I had created earlier in my MSSQLLOCALDB?? Now can't I retrieve the data from the database created by me?

Comment: Do you see your database files in your user directory? `dir %USERPROFILE%\*.mdf`

Comment: Yes. I can see the database files and their log files in my user directory. But when I try to open them it is showing that those files are used by OS and by various programs. Editing or modify them could damage the system.

Comment: Open them with what? Database files are managed by SQL Server; you can't open them in an application. You should be able to recreate the instance as I suggested and then attach the databases (mdf files), assuming they are not being used by another SQL instance.

Comment: This is the first time am using the SQL server nd SQL server management studio. I had learnt how to implement a database in the VS. I don't have much knowledge as am a beginner. Can you please clarify my doubt. If I uninstall and then reinstall all these applications will my issue be resolved? If I do so, will I lose my databases? However those databases are not much important to me. But to practice a course I need one of them. I can also recreate them. But I want my doubt to be get clarified. Thank you.

Comment: Uninstalling/re-installing seems like overkill. Before doing that, recreate the instance as I suggested. Then connect to `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` with SSMS and attach each the mdf file with a SQL query like `EXEC sp_attach_db 'YourDatabaseName','C:\Users\YourUserName\YourDatabaseName.mdf';`

Comment: Thank you. I will follow what u have suggested. But there is an attach option in SSMS. I can browse the files and attach them. But am not able to see the mdf files in my users folder. I mentioned that am able to see the database files and log files in my users folder. Are those and mdf files same?

Comment: The files you attached are the ones in the location you browsed to. The are different if in the same directly. If you can see your tables in the databases you attached, you're good.

Comment: @DanGuzman there is a typo on your first comment: `sqlqlocaldb`. If anyone else (like myself) is trying that command, please change it to `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message in the Windows log about the missing registry value suggests your localdb instance is corrupt. You can recreate the MSSQLLocalDB instance and registry entries by running these commands from a command prompt:

```
sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB -s
```

Comment: Finally! A solution that works! You're the man Dan.

Comment: What if I don't want to lose all of my data? Every solution I have found says I need to wipe the database and start over? Why?

Comment: @Caleb, if the database file exists, you should be able to attach it after recreating the instance. Find the data file(s) with `dir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\mssqllocaldb\*.mdf"`